# How do I redirect a user to another page when a countdown timer gets to 0?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
constructor(){
    super()

    this.state = {
        countDown: 6
    }}
componentDidMount(){

    this.myInterval = setInterval(() =>{
        browserhistory.push("/time-up")componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.state.countDown === 0){
      browserHistory.push("/time-up");
}
}
```

//I want to redirect the user to a page called "time up" when the countdown gets to zero in the componentDidUpdate lifecycle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: Off topic: Shouldn't you be using `setTimeout` instead? Interval is for repeating events. If you insist, for some reason, on using interval, it should at least be cleared before you redirect the user, with `clearInterval(this.myInterval)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `browserHistory.push("/time-up");`, add `window.location = "/time-up"`

Comment: Done, I just updated my answer, I thought it was pretty clear, since he has similar code to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to redirect to /time-up so I guess you're trying to do a internal navigation. You can do it by using the history prop coming from react-router

Instead of `browserHistory.push("/time-up");` you can write `this.props.history.push("/time-up")`

If you don't have the history prop, you can inject by augmenting your component with the `withRouter` HOC

Answer (score 0):

To redirect from `componentDidUpdate()` use this,

```
componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.state.countDown === 0){
       window.location.href = "/time-up"
    }
}
```

Another way is to use [Redirect](https://medium.com/@anneeb/redirecting-in-react-4de5e517354a) from `react-router-dom` package,

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.state.countDown === 0){
       <Redirect to={'/time-up'} />
    }
}
```

**Note: Your code snippet is messy, you are using `componentDidUpdate` inside `componentDidMount`? If yes, then you should not do that. Both are different methods and cannot be called inside another, place both differently.**

Comment: I used both lifecycle methods in different lines. I used the window.location.href and it worked, but I'll use the Redirect component since is cleaner. Thank you.

Comment: @ManuelHelamanSotoAlvarez Great. If this solves your problem then you can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

you need to decrement the time or it will sit at 6